# Unable redirect page on form submission in django

Tags: python, html, django, redirect

I am trying to implement a document search engine in django. The main page has a text box in which the user is supposed to enter a query. On entering the query, the user will be redirected to a page that will contain the titles of document relevant to their query. However, I'm unable to redirect to a new page on query submission. My app is named `search` and this is the page that loads on opening `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/`

`index.html`

```
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'search/style.css' %}" />
<title>muGoogle</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
<h4 class = 'mugoogle'>muGoogle</h4>
<form  class="form-wrapper" method = "GET" action = "{% url 'doc_scorer'%}">
    <input type="text" name = 'query' class="textbox rounded" placeholder="Search docs related to..." required>
    <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
    url(r'^search$', views.search),
    url(r'^index$', views.index),
    url(r'', views.doc_scorer, name="doc_scorer"),
]
```

the `views.py` file

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
import os
from other_code import some_function

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template("search/index.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

def search(request):
    return HttpResponse("search is under construction")

def doc_scorer(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    context = {'query':some_function(query)}
    return render_to_response('query_results.html', context)
```

I want to redirect the results this page.

`query_results.html`

```
{{ context['query'] }}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error or something?

Comment: @nik_m no errors. there is no redirection. on submission, only the url changes nothing else

Comment: Does the `doc_scorer` is actually called? Put a `print(query)` underneath `query = request.GET.....` and check if it is actually printed.

Comment: What could be an enhancement is that you can implement ajax on the text input field to display the possible keywords as it is a search engine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index view and your doc_scorer view seem to have the same url ('/' in both cases). Hence, if the form sends its data to '/', it will be processed by the index view, which comes first in the list of url patterns. You should change the url conf of your doc_scorer view:

```
urlpatterns = [...
    url('^doc_scorer/$', views.doc_scorer, name='doc_scorer'),
]
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Another quick question. on query submission, I want the redirected url to be of the form `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?query=`. How do I achieve that

Comment: Your form `action` points to `{% url 'doc_scorer' %}`, let's assume that this is resolved to `localhost:8000/doc_scorer/'. Since your form's `method` is "GET", the browser will automatically pass any submitted data as a part of the url and will call the url `localhost:8000/doc_scorer/?query=<whatever>`. So, I guess you don't need to do anything special to achieve what you aim for... Please note that the form in your template is not submitting to '/search/'.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `url (r '^ $', views.index)` is preferentially executed.
Try changing index view. like this.

```
def index(request):
    if not request.GET.get('query'):
        return render_to_response('search/index.html', {})
    # search execution
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    context = {'query':some_function(query)}
    return render_to_response('query_results.html', context)
```